# MongoDB C# Driver (2.7) and serialization issues

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm currently having a strange issue with the latest mongodb c# driver (2.7), inheritance and serialization.

Here is a super simplified class hierarchy that I'm using:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    protected BaseClass(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(Guid id) : base(id) {}
}
```

When I try to register the class for mongo serialization, I am getting an error:

```
var type = typeof(DerivedClass);

if (BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(type))
    return;

var cm = new BsonClassMap(type);
cm.AutoMap();

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(cm);
```

The error is:

```
The memberInfo argument must be for class DerivedClass, but was for class BaseClass.
Parameter name: memberInfo
```

Now, and this is where things start to get weird, when I tried to understand what was happening I made some changes to the BaseClass or the DerivedClass.

**ANY** of the two changes listed below will make the `RegisterClassMap` method work without errors...

**change 1: adding a second, unused property on BaseClass**

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Test { get; }

    protected BaseClass(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

**change 2: changing the Id property to have a non-private setter (any other works)**

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    protected BaseClass(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

My question is... what is happening? While I may agree that for the serializer you should have an accessible setter for every property on the class that you want to map (in this case, DerivedClass), why the case #1 is actually not giving any error?